# Json parsing in java to obtain a value

Tags: java, json

[{"value":"meeting","confidence":1,"type":"value"}]

Parse this JSON Response to achieve the value in a string such that meeting should be stored in a String variable

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask].  This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

info has Model ;)
import org.json.*;

```
            String strResponce=response.body().string();
            Log.i("WEBSERVICE",strResponce);
            switch (response.code())
            {
                case 200:
                    try
                    {
                        JsonArray array=new JsonParser().parse(strResponce).getAsJsonArray();

                        for(JsonElement element:array)
                        {

                            final JsonObject object=element.getAsJsonObject();
                            AndroidInfo info=new AndroidInfo();
                            info.setName(object.get("name").getAsString());
                            info.setApi(object.get("api").getAsString());
                            infos.add(info);
                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    txtResult.setText(txtResult.getText()+"\n"+object.get("name").getAsString());
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                    catch (JsonSyntaxException e){}
```